# Consecutive numbering and labels in tcolorbox

Tags: cross-referencing, numbering, tcolorbox, labels

Those days I write a book, and I use framed boxes `tcolorbox`. Have a look:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amsfonts,amssymb,mathtools}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{tcolorbox,xcolor}
\theoremstyle{definition}

\makeatletter

\tcbuselibrary{theorems}

\newtcbtheorem[number within=section]{mytheo}{Theorem}%
{colback=black!5,colframe=red!35!black,fonttitle=\bfseries}{th}

\newtcbtheorem[number within=section]{myprop}{Proposition}%
{colback=black!5,colframe=red!50!black,fonttitle=\bfseries}{th}

\newtcbtheorem[number within=section]{mylem}{Lemma}%
{colback=black!5,colframe=red!50!black,fonttitle=\bfseries}{th}

\newtcbtheorem[number within=section]{mypor}{Corollary}%
{colback=black!5,colframe=red!35!black,fonttitle=\bfseries}{th}

\newtcbtheorem[number within=section]{myax}{Axiom}%
{colback=black!5,colframe=blue!35!black,fonttitle=\bfseries}{th}


\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{udidot}

\begin{document}

\newtheorem{defin}{Definition}[section]
\newtheorem{prt}{Remark}[section]
\newtheorem{prts}{Remarks}[section]
\newtheorem{exmp}{Example}[section]
\newtheorem{exmps}{Examples}[section]
\newtheorem*{note}{Note}

\chapter{Maximal and Prime Ideals}

\section{Maximal Ideals}  

\begin{defin}  
Let $R$ a commutative ring with $1_R$ ...
\end{defin}

\begin{myprop}{Maximal Ideals Criterion}{}
    \label{Max Id Crit}
Let $R$ a commutative ring with $1_R$ ...
\end{myprop}

From the Proposition \ref{Max Id Crit}, ...

\end{document}
```

As you can see, I would like to use these frames only for theorems, propositions, lemmas, corollaries and axioms (and *not* for the definitions). Also I would like to keep the choice to write some of them (for instance, a theorem) *without* these frames.

**My questions are:**

1. How can we have consecutive numbering in the whole text?
2. Ase you can see, we face a problem with labels in the reference of theorems etc. How can we solve it?

[image]

Answer (score 6):

1. The tcbtheorem environments allow you to use counters from other tcbtheorems as well as existing LaTeX counters. It will be easier to define the standard LaTeX theorems first (all sharing the same counter), and then define the tcbtheorems (using that same counter).
2. The problem is that a label for a tcbtheorem environment needs to be passed as an option to that environment in order for it to work correctly. This is not standard LaTeX behaviour (you would have noticed that labelling and referencing your definition environment would have worked without a hitch).

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amsfonts,amssymb,mathtools}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{tcolorbox,xcolor}
\theoremstyle{definition}
% Define amsthm theorems first
\newtheorem{defin}{Definition}[section] % Creates a new counter, number within section
\newtheorem{prt}[defin]{Remark} % Putting [defin] in second position uses defin's counter instead of creating a new one
\newtheorem{prts}[defin]{Remarks} % Again share defin's counter
\newtheorem{exmp}[defin]{Example} % etc.
\newtheorem{exmps}[defin]{Examples}
\newtheorem*{note}{Note}

\tcbuselibrary{theorems}
% use counter*=defin to make each tcbtheorem share defin's counter
\newtcbtheorem[use counter*=defin, number within=section]{mytheo}{Theorem}%
{colback=black!5,colframe=red!35!black,fonttitle=\bfseries}{th}
\newtcbtheorem[use counter*=defin, number within=section]{myprop}{Proposition}%
{colback=black!5,colframe=red!50!black,fonttitle=\bfseries}{th}
\newtcbtheorem[use counter*=defin, number within=section]{mylem}{Lemma}%
{colback=black!5,colframe=red!50!black,fonttitle=\bfseries}{th}
\newtcbtheorem[use counter*=defin, number within=section]{mypor}{Corollary}%
{colback=black!5,colframe=red!35!black,fonttitle=\bfseries}{th}
\newtcbtheorem[use counter*=defin, number within=section]{myax}{Axiom}%
{colback=black!5,colframe=blue!35!black,fonttitle=\bfseries}{th}
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{udidot}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Maximal and Prime Ideals}
\section{Maximal Ideals}  
% Normal labelling
\begin{defin}  \label{first_def}
Let $R$ a commutative ring with $1_R$ ...
\end{defin}
% tcbtheorem labelling
\begin{myprop}[label=prop:maximal]{Maximal Ideals Criterion}{}
Let $R$ a commutative ring with $1_R$ ...
\end{myprop}
From the Proposition \ref{prop:maximal} and definition \ref{first_def}\ldots
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: output]

As an aside, I would recommend using the `cleveref` package which can easily be set-up with the each tcbtheorem so as to produce a named reference instead of just a number e.g. 'proposition 1.1.2' vs '1.1.2'. That way you don't have to worry about whether you're referencing a theorem, or a definition, or a proposition etc. each time.

FYI There was a rogue `\makeatletter` in your code.

Comment: Works perfect, thank you. But, why \makeatletter is a rogue?

Comment: It wasn't doing anything. In general \makeatletter should only be used 'temporarily', being following shortly by \makeatother.

Answer (score 4):

The key is the *tcolorbox* options `use counter=<another counter>` and `use counter from= <counter from another tcolorbox>`

**Update** taking into account  the OP comments:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amsfonts,amssymb,mathtools}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{tcolorbox,xcolor}
\theoremstyle{definition}

%\makeatletter

\tcbuselibrary{theorems}

\newtcbtheorem[number within=section,use counter=defin]{mytheo}{Theorem}%
{colback=black!5,colframe=red!35!black,fonttitle=\bfseries}{th}

\newtcbtheorem[number within=section,use counter =defin]{myprop}{Proposition}%
{colback=black!5,colframe=red!50!black,fonttitle=\bfseries}{th}

\newtcbtheorem[number within=section,use counter= defin]{mylem}{Lemma}%
{colback=black!5,colframe=red!50!black,fonttitle=\bfseries}{th}

\newtcbtheorem[number within=section,use counter=defin]{mycor}{Corollary}%
{colback=black!5,colframe=red!35!black,fonttitle=\bfseries}{th}

\newtcbtheorem[number within=section,use counter=defin]{myax}{Axiom}%
{colback=black!5,colframe=blue!35!black,fonttitle=\bfseries}{th}


\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{udidot}

\begin{document}

\newtheorem{defin}{Definition}[section]
\newtheorem{prt}[defin]{Remark}
\newtheorem{prts}[defin]{Remarks}
\newtheorem{exmp}[defin]{Example}%[section]
\newtheorem{exmps}[defin]{Examples}
\newtheorem*{note}{Note}

\chapter{Maximal and Prime Ideals}

\section{Maximal Ideals}  

\begin{defin} 
\label{def:commutative ring}
Let $R$ a commutative ring with $1_R$ ...
\end{defin}

\begin{myprop}{Maximal Ideals Criterion}{Max Id Crit}

Let $R$ a commutative ring with $1_R$ ...
\end{myprop}

From the Proposition \ref{th:Max Id Crit}, 

See definition \ref{def:commutative ring}

\begin{exmp} \label{ex: my example}
my example
\end{exmp}

example : \ref{ex: my example}



\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. It works nice, but I have one more question. How do we refer to a non framed definition or proposition etc? Normally with "\label{}"?

Comment: @Chris Do you mean a definition  created by a `\newtheorem` or by a `\newtcbtheorem` ?

Comment: From newtheorem :)

Comment: @Chris `\label{mylabel}` then `\ref{mylabel}` where *mylabel* can be replaced with something like *def:commutative ring*

Comment: There is and another issue: if we write down a framed proposition and then a non framed example, the counter in the example starts from the beginning. Can we fix it?

Comment: @Chris Replace `\newtheorem{exmp}{Example}[section]` by `\newtheorem{exmp}[defin]{Example}`

Comment: @Chris answer updated